# How do i query the ng-model table with xpath in selenium and java

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get table from [DOCTYPE Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gznFz.png) through xpath or by className in Selenium/java. But i cannot find the locator. How can i get the table through selenium java. Both below paths are not working.

Table screenshot is at [Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBeIi.png)

```
WebElement tableElement= driver.findElement(By.className("table table-striped"));       
        
WebElement tableElement1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody"));
```

I would like to get all the rows in the table through selenium.

I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody"}

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".table\.table\-striped"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's a very interesting question because you highlight a well-know phenomena (which, for some reason, skip the radar of many developers).

Today, we are heavily relying on modern web stacks (Yes, `angularjs` is still considered as modern) and thus, exposed to the "elements" of it.

As users, it's fun and intuitive when page loades in a fancy way (aka `lazy loaded`) which means: the page loads it's essential resources first, and only then the rest. You mentioned a table, which probably query the data via an API call and may not be rendered when the page load. For us, humans, it's seems pretty fast but - the element is not there when the page first initiate.

**How to check it?**

go to you page, wait for everything to load properly, then hit the `right-click` mouse button and choose `view page source`. Is the table there? if not - it is lazy loaded and you need to.. wait for it

**How to fix this?**

Let's start with reading the [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) and fully understand what we are doing (and when.. and why). Then we may use a mechanism proposed there - itmay look something like this:

```
WebElement table = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                      .until(driver -> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table .table-striped")));
```

I assume that the `.table-stripped` element is inside a `table` element - but you can play with it according to your html structure until you get the proper selector for your table

You may need to use this approach more than you think, so - take your time to properly educate yourself and feel comfortable before rushing into the next problem. Happy coding